# How to resolve 'Missing constraint: Import-Package: sun.misc ' on JavaSE-11

Tags: java, eclipse, birt, rcp

I am trying to upgrade my RCP app from Java8 to Java11.

The app contains BIRT which in turn depends on `com.github.librepdf.openpdf` and imports the package `sun.misc`. This results in `Missing constraint: Import-Package: sun.misc`.

As far as I can determine looking at their manifests, each of these bundles (as well as all my bundles) target Java 11 so I cannot understand why the `sun.misc` is imported in the first place.

I found this fairly recent issue https://issueantenna.com/repo/LibrePDF/OpenPDF/issues/704 but there doesn't appear to be a solution.

Can I supply `sun.misc` from elsewhere or is there another solution?

Comment: may be you need to use java version 8. But if you are on java version > 8 and < 17 then you can add `--illegal-access=permit` command line option while running the app and for java 17 `"--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` ref: https://openjdk.org/jeps/403

Comment: I guess your RCP application needs `--add-exports jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED`, but better get rid of the use of `sun.misc` at all.